# Hilla: Radio button value not accessible in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vaadin, hilla, binders

I am not able to access values of multiple radio button groups and pass those values to the backend.

```
<vaadin-radio-group theme="vertical" name="radio1">
    <label>Staff were friendly and helpful </label>
    <vaadin-radio-button  value="25" label="Yes" ></vaadin-radio-button>
    <vaadin-radio-button  value="26" label="No" ></vaadin-radio-button>
</vaadin-radio-group><br>

        
<vaadin-radio-group theme="vertical" name="radio2" > 
    <label>Staff informed you when your car was ready </label>
    <vaadin-radio-button  value="27" label="Yes" ></vaadin-radio-button>
    <vaadin-radio-button  value="28" label="No" ></vaadin-radio-button>
</vaadin-radio-group>
```

I need to display the selected value for both radio1 and radio2 in the log.

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();


  let selectedValue;
  for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
      selectedValue = radioButtons[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How is `radioButtons` defined?

Comment: `const form = document.getElementById('survey-form');
const radioButtons = form.elements['question'];`

Comment: Do you see any values in the `radioButtons` array? The queryselector looks a bit odd to me. What happens if you do `document.querySelectorAll('vaadin-radio-group')`?